# SELECT SUM, Exibir apenas uma linha de resultado

Tags: sql-server

Bom dia, tudo bem?
Estou fazendo uma consulta SQL onde preciso exibir somente em uma linha as informações:

> Produto | QuantidadeCompras | QuantidadeVendas | ValorCusto |
> ValorVenda | Fornecedor

Mas no resultado saem 2 linhas (o "problema" é quando insiro no *select* o `cod_Fornecedor`).

```
SELECT 
    dbo.fncFormataString(p.CodigoInterno,10,'0') + ' - ' + p.Descricao AS Produto,
    IsNull(Totais.Entradas,0) AS QuantidadeCompras,
    IsNull(Totais.Saidas,0) AS QuantidadeVendas,
    p.Custo_Atual AS ValorCusto,
    p.Vlr_Venda AS ValorVenda,
    f.Nome AS Fornecedor

FROM (
    SELECT 
        CodProduto, 
        Cod_Fornecedor,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Condicao = 'EC' or Condicao = 'ES' THEN Qdade ELSE 0 END) AS Entradas,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Condicao = 'SV' or Condicao = 'SS' or Condicao = 'SN' THEN Qdade ELSE 0 END) AS Saida
        
    FROM
    Movimento_Itens

    WHERE 
        (Data Between '01-01-2022' and '31-12-2022') 

    GROUP BY
        CodProduto,
        Cod_Fornecedor
 ) Totais

INNER JOIN produtos p ON Totais.CodProduto = p.CodigoInterno
LEFT JOIN Fornecedores f ON Totais.Cod_Fornecedor = f.Codigo

ORDER BY 
    p.CodigoInterno,
    p.Descricao,
    COALESCE(f.Nome, f.RazaoSocial)
```

Comment: isso quer dizer que exibe duas linhas com códigos diferentes? se for, não sei o que está errado - já que seriam fornecedores diferentes

Comment: Pouco claro mas pesquise por STRING_AGG , STUFF , PIVOT e CASE

Comment: para exibir uma única linha, é preciso que todos os campos tenham valores iguais... o `sum` soma "coisas iguais", o `group by` ajuda a agrupar, mas se tiver valores diferentes, vai trazer linhas diferentes